# Mail migration monitoring

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have the following script to monitor some mail migrations.

It works fine but the time doesn't display properly and when the size goes above 1024MB it goes blank.

```
get-moverequest| get-moverequeststatistics |Sort-Object PercentComplete -Descending | 
  ft displayname, @{l=" % "; expression="percentcomplete"},
    @{l="Size";e={$_.Totalitemsize.value.toString().SubString(0,($_.totalitemsize.ToString().IndexOf("MB")))}} ,
    @{l="Moved";e={$_.BytesTransferred.ToString().SubString(0,($_.BytesTransferred.ToString().IndexOf("MB")))}},
    @{l="Rate";e={$_.BytesTransferredPerMinute.ToString().SubString(0,($_.BytesTransferredPerMinute.ToString().IndexOf("MB")))}}, 
    @{l="Time";e={$_.totalinprogressduration}},statusdetail  -AutoSize|  Out-String
```

If I change the "ToMB()" to "ToGB()" then the lines are blanks until it gets to 1GB

Also the time doesn't display properly as it shows HH:MM:SS:xxxxxx how can I change this to be true time

[image: This is what I see]

TIA

Andy

Comment: What do you mean by "true" time?

Comment: It currently shows Hours, minutes, seconds and parts of a second. I want hh:mm:ss only

Comment: To format TimeStamp You should write `$timestamp.ToString('dd\.hh\:mm\:ss')`. In that case it is `$_.totalinprogressduration.ToString('dd\.hh\:mm\:ss')` or in PowerShell style `'{0:dd\.hh\:mm\:ss}' -f $_.totalinprogressduration`.

Comment: I tried that and the time column goes blank

Comment: To remove the time seconds fraction change `@{l="Time";e={$_.totalinprogressduration}}` to `@{l="Time";e={$_.totalinprogressduration.Split('.')[0]}}''`

Comment: Size and Moved seem to already have an algorythm that adapts to the current scale so you should show the unchanged values